# Filtering logic with timedelta in panel data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime, timedelta

For each id `id`, i want to apply the following logic of filtering:

First identify which is the oldest time for each id.
Second if the following rows had a time difference of less than 5 minutes from the oldest time, drop it.
Once 5 minutes pass from the oldest time for each id, find the following oldest time and repeat again the rule if the following rows had a time difference of less than 5 minutes from this new oldest time, drop them

```
df
               time  track  id
2018-07-06 08:34:44       1   1
2018-07-06 08:35:46       1   1
2018-07-19 09:15:50       1   1
2018-07-19 09:17:23       1   1
2018-07-06 07:34:44       1   2
2018-07-06 07:36:46       1   2
2018-07-06 07:37:50       1   2
2018-07-06 07:37:53       1   2
```

Expected result

```
               time  track  id
2018-07-06 08:34:44       1   1
2018-07-19 09:15:50       1   1
2018-07-06 07:34:44       1   2
```

Comment: There's an import question of ordering for these types of operations. If your times for a single `id` are `8:00` `8:04` and `8:08` do you keep just `8:00`? If you drop `8:04` on the first pass, then `8:08` should not be dropped based on your logic. Just need to know which way to handle this situation

Comment: In your example, you should keep 8:00 and 8:09 because 08:04 is less than 5 minutes from the oldest time. It's like whenever you reach 08:05 you have to find the new oldest time and repeat the same filtering logic

Comment: Why is 9:17 dropped when it's on an entirely different day?

Comment: changed it :), thank you

Comment: Show us the code you have so far. Also, since it likely sorts the df, please revise your sample input to show rows in chronological order.